# How i save video with CameraKit

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera, android-manifest, android-ffmpeg

I'm using CameraKit, and i can take picture with it, but i don't know how to record a video. I search in documentation and i found an Event and two methods to start and stop the video, I search in FFMPEG and i failed to implemented, if there is any solution please help me.

```
cameraKitView.captureVideo(VideoCallback callback)
cameraKitView.startVideo()
cameraKitView.stopVideo()
```

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_capture = findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
        cameraKitView = findViewById(R.id.camera);
        // btn_capture.setOnClickListener(photoOnClickListener);

        btn_capture.setOnClickListener(videoOnClickListener);

    }

 private View.OnClickListener videoOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                   cameraKitView.captureVideo(new CameraKitView.VideoCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onVideo(final CameraKitView cameraKitView, final Object o) {
                    cameraKitView.startVideo();
 cameraKitView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //cameraKitView.stopVideo();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "video stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, 2500);

           }
};
```

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.camerakit.CameraKitView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:padding="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_settings"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Which version of Camera Kit are you using?

Comment: @Dhaval i'm using the version 1.0.0-beta3.11

Comment: When I was implementing with the same version I stuck with same problem as you do now. If I am not mistaken, they haven't implemented Video Recording functionality as of now in beta 3.11 version. 
If you try to read documentation, you won't find any link related to video recording as well. So in my opinion, you should use stable version (0.13.4) for now.

Comment: @Dhaval the stable version support video recording or no ?? and how you solve your problem

Comment: Yes. Stable version does contains methods for recording video. I will post my code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Following example is in Kotlin but you can easily understand the terminology for Java as well.

Use following stable version of CameraKit

```
implementation "com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.13.5"
```

Then you can use following method to capture Video

```
cameraKitView.captureVideo("YOUR_VIDE_FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENTION(.mp4)") { cameraKitVideo ->
    if (cameraKitVideo.videoFile != null) {
        // Save video or post it to server
    }
}
```

As long as I know, above method is only available in stable versions of CameraKit. It is not included in newer(beta) version of library.

Comment: I get the error: cameraKitVideo needs an explicit type - tried with cameraKitVideo:CameraKitVideo, doesn't work